# Find out last month's data when rolling into a new year

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight

Currently, I am using this code to look at the previous month's data for quicksight in Amazon's Athena (this first part works*):

```
SELECT month, count(1)
FROM table1
WHERE CAST(EXTRACT(month from now()) - 1 as VARCHAR(2)) = month
GROUP BY month
```

The challenge is how to ensure that this code will work once we roll over into a new year? I currently have

```
SELECT month, count(1)
FROM table1
WHERE CASE WHEN( month = '1' THEN month = '13'
ELSE month
END)
CAST(EXTRACT(month from now()) - 1 as VARCHAR(2)) = month
GROUP BY month
```

To clarify, month was input as a string, hence the CAST as VARCHAR(2) to get "01" through "12".
My thought process behind this was that if month = '01', then it reads it as '13', then extracts '1', equaling '12'. But not sure if that will work

Comment: Do you store the year in your table? Your query does not show it. Please show us sample data and desired results to clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`date_add`](https://prestosql.io/docs/0.172/functions/datetime.html#date_add) function to subtract one month from today:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD('month', -1, NOW())
```

Alternatively you can subtract an interval of one month to achieve the same results:

```
SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL '1' MONTH
```

In both cases you can then use `MONTH(…)` or `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM …)` to get the month number.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
where month = extract(month from now()) - 1 or
      (extract(month from now()) = 1 and month = 12)
```

Comment: I should clarify that month was input as a string, so I had to cast it to get the VARCHAR(2)